# Fill image to screen width Xamarin android

Tags: android, imageview, width, xamarin.android, screen

Iam creating an Android project with Xamarin.I have a Image that I download from a Url and show it in my ImageView.

This is my code:-

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessageImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

I download it like so:-

```
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(viewHolder.ImgMessageImageView, item.MessageImage, Resource.Drawable.placeholder, 120000);
```

Right now, the default placeholder fits the screen properly., but when it gets replaced by the actual image from the url, the new image does not fill the screen width.

How do I do it? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
            try
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                 Bitmap placeholderBM= BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.placeholder);

                using (var drawable = new BitmapDrawable(placeholderBM))
                {
                    (FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgMessageImage)).SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
                placeholderBM.Dispose();

            });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string test = ex.Message;
            }
```

Try to fit your next image which comes with urlDrawable from your view. This will override and you can properly put it on the first image's place.